# Pandora is playing songs in the wrong language

Tags: pandora, localization

I'm trying to create a new Pandora station with the song "Enrique Iglesias - I Like It" as the seed. The problem is that all the songs that come up are in Spanish, even though the song seed is in English. Even after thumbs-downing the songs that come up, it still only plays songs in Spanish.

How can I get it to start playing songs in English that are similar to this song?

Note: I'm only having problems with this station, other stations play songs in English.

Answer (score 1):

I played with Pandora for a while and while yes, just thumb-down'ing songs on I Like It station doesn't bring up English songs — but, after a while, I started getting Brazilian latin with “portuguese lyrics” as one of the traits why it was selected, meaning that my thumbs-downing of Spanish songs did have some effect.

As far as I remember, Pandora doesn't grade songs individually, but rather albums as a whole, so if this particular song is from a mostly Spanish-language album, it will still have “spanish lyrics” as an attribute, so it's strongly biased towards Spanish-language songs.

So, I guess there is no easy solution to get English-language latin music precisely on Pandora.

Comment: Update in 2017: Seeding a station with a song from an English-language-only album by a typically-non-English artist ("Exodus" by Utada) still results in a mostly-foreign-language station.